# Падеж числительных

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Привожу отрывок из литературного произведения:

> *Наверное, десять дней вам мало, — говорит Хетти.*

Почему в данном предложении слово *десять* не стоит в родительном падеже, как требует этого слово *мало*?

Answer (score 2):

***Наверное, десять дней вам мало.***

Конечно, в таких конструкциях обычно используется Р.п.

Но не всегда.

Попробуем изменить предложение:

***Наверное, десять дней (И.п.) — это мало.*** Тире ставится между подлежащим и именным сказуемым.

***Наверное, десять дней (И.п.) вам  мало***. Дополнение между подлежащим и именным сказуемым.